# JSON .Net Serialization not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have this class:

```
[Serializable]
public class ServerResponse
{
    public string[] Response { get; set; }
    public object Packet { get; set; }

    public ServerResponse(string[] response, object packet){
        this.Response = response;
        this.Packet = packet;
    }

    public string[] getResponse() { return this.Response; }
    public object getPacket() { return this.Packet; }
}
```

And use the following to convert to JSON:

```
    static void writeToClient(TcpClient client, object message)
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = NetworkHelper.GetMessageAsBytes(json);

        clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        clientStream.Flush();
    }
```

However, the `Packet` is never serialized. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Sample output:

```
{"Response":["message","Authenticated"],"Packet":{}}
```

And this is the actual class I'm attempting to serialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class ActiveGameSession
{
    private LoginServerSettings serverSettings;
    private List<UserCharacter> sessionCharacters = new List<UserCharacter>();
    private UserAccount sessionAccount;

    public ActiveGameSession()
    {
        this.sessionCharacters = new List<UserCharacter>();
        this.sessionAccount = null;
        this.serverSettings = null;
    }

    public ActiveGameSession(List<UserCharacter> chars, UserAccount session)
    {
        this.sessionCharacters = chars;
        this.sessionAccount = session;
    }

    #region setters
    public void setCharacters(List<UserCharacter> chars)
    {
        this.sessionCharacters = chars;
    }

    public void setSession(UserAccount session)
    {
        this.sessionAccount = session;
    }

    public void setServerSettings(LoginServerSettings settings)
    {
        this.serverSettings = settings;
    }
    #endregion

    #region getters
    public List<UserCharacter> getCharacters()
    {
        return this.sessionCharacters;
    }

    public UserAccount getAccount()
    {
        return this.sessionAccount;
    }

    public LoginServerSettings getSettings()
    {
        return this.serverSettings;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.NET may not support serialization of an object of type Object. Try using a more concrete type. If you want to have multiple packet types you can try using generics or derive from a common base class.

Edit:
Also there are no public properties of ActiveGameSession to be deserialized, please note that the getXXX, setXXX methods is not recognized as properties.

Comment: This was the best answer. Thanks for your help! Once I cast the object and exposed the members it was all groovy!

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast the object representing the Packet to a type that JSON.NET can serialize. Try casting to a string and try again.